# Understanding Crashes & ANRs at Developer console

Tags: android

On my Developer Console I can see that my app as a crash. It is a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Opening the crash Stack trace I get this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nutridatalite.mgm/com.nutridatalite.mgm.Infodata}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3770)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.nutridatalite.mgm.Infodata.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
... 11 more
```

I can see the Class where the error is being generated but I can't understand what is causing the error.

Is there a way to have a more detailed log?
When using the phone connected to the IDE when we have a crash, the line number where the error happens it's shown.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post this - com.nutridatalite.mgm.Infodata.onCreate

Comment: @Eng.Fouad I don't know. `Infodata? only has 800 lines...